# Why isn't my function returning the string?

Tags: php, recursion

I have a function that first looks for premium brands to add to a string. If there is not enough premium brands, it continues and ads non-premium brands (max 4 brands).

I'm able to echo the string inside the function and it shows 4 brands, but I'm not able to return the string. Why is that?

```
$bnames = addBrandNameToTitle($model);
echo $bnames; // This is empty

function addBrandNameToTitle($model, $brandNames = array(), $ispremium = true){
    if($ispremium):
        foreach ($model->brands as $brand):
            if ($brand->isPremium() && count($brandNames)  < 4):
                array_push($brandNames, $brand->name);
            endif;

            if(count($brandNames)  >= 4){
                return implode(',', $brandNames);
            }
        endforeach;
        // If not enough premium, add non-premium brands
        addBrandNameToTitle($model, $brandNames, false);
    else:
        foreach ($model->brands as $brand):
            if (!$brand->isPremium() && count($brandNames) < 4):
                array_push($brandNames, $brand->name);
            endif;
        endforeach;
        $bnames = implode(',', $brandNames);
        echo $bnames; // <-- This lists 4 brands
        return $bnames; // <-- But this is not returning the string. Why?
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this section of code, you forgot to return the value

```
// If not enough premium, add non-premium brands
return addBrandNameToTitle($model, $brandNames, false);  // Add a return
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I've never had to use `return` before. Can you explain why I need that and simply not just calling the function recursively with parameters?

Comment: The first time you call the function, `$isPremium` is `true`.  This means that the first part of the if statement is executed.  The only `return` statement is in the `else` part, which doesn't get executed.  Because there is no explicit return, the function returns nothing.  This is regardless of any recursion or anything else that might be happening.